# heroku db:pull to ubuntu postgresql

Tags: postgresql, heroku, ssh, taps

I want to migrate my application from Heroku to my own ubuntu server. What is the correct syntax to do this using `taps/heroku db:pull`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are moving data between a local and cloud database both of which are Postgres you should follow the instructions on Heroku's Devcenter:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-data-between-plans

Answer (score 0):

You would simply do `heroku db:pull` to pull the database from Heroku to your local db which you would then backup and restore to your own server. If it's a large database you might want to look into Heroku pgbackups as an alternative as it will provide you with a downloadable backup.

Note: If you want to migrate between databases, ie postgres => mysql then you would have to use the db:pull approach.